UPS Shipping API using OAUTH 2.0
UPS wants me to start using OAuth 2.0 to validate the shipping label generation.
I have been able to generate and save in database the access token, refresh token as well as the expiry time.
For this I followed the guide here:
https://developer.ups.com/api/reference/oauth/authorization-code?loc=en_US
When I use them to generate the shipping label, I get this error:

Error generating shipping label: {"response":{"errors":[{"code":"251003","message":"Invalid bearer Token"}]}}

For shipping label generation, I am using this guide:
https://developer.ups.com/api/reference?loc=en_US#operation/Shipment
Can someone please help.
Wanted the shipping label image to be generated.

I mixed up the url path which gave me the same error message.
I had

ship/v2403/shipments

instead of

api/shipments/v2403/ship

Also check your headers. They are case sensitive.

Have you gotten to purchasing labels yet? I'm implementing now but don't see an easy way to just charge the label tot he customers account they authenticated with.  The other option is to enter credit card info, but that's not ideal. You can use their account number, but you can't access that in the API.
